# Retrieve single Data From MySQL Server DB in Android using Volley and PHP and json

Tags: java, php, json

Here PHP code data coming from server but null values  how its set everything is works fine without error please explain

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $id  = $_GET['id'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE id='".$id."'";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $result = array();

    array_push($result,array(
        "name"=>$res['name'],
        "address"=>$res['address'],
        "vc"=>$res['vicechancellor']
        )
    );

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the $sql to the below once and try ....

$sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE id=$id";